# AWS Cloud9 showing `no access` under permission, any idea?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

I am trying out a workshop for AWS EKS using Cloud9, and have this properties set:

```
aws cloud9 describe-environment-memberships --environment-id 23104b5e40ee441ab9cefb8b7f7164dc
{
    "memberships": [
        {
            "permissions": "read-write",
            "userId": "AIDATYVU6WKIS6LOM4NXB",
            "userArn": "arn:aws:iam::259151278737:user/eks-workshop-gitops",
            "environmentId": "23104b5e40ee441ab9cefb8b7f7164dc"
        },
        {
            "permissions": "read-write",
            "userId": "AIDATYVU6WKITNU6UKSNC",
            "userArn": "arn:aws:iam::259151278737:user/Sandbox_contributor",
            "environmentId": "23104b5e40ee441ab9cefb8b7f7164dc"
        },
        {
            "permissions": "owner",
            "userId": "AIDATYVU6WKIV2ZOAKKMY",
            "userArn": "arn:aws:iam::259151278737:user/it.terraform_user",
            "environmentId": "23104b5e40ee441ab9cefb8b7f7164dc"
        }
    ]
}
```

My IAM is under that *Sandbox_contributor* as seen above.
Status of my Cloud9 environment is as follows:

```
aws cloud9 describe-environment-status --environment-id 23104b5e40ee441ab9cefb8b7f7164dc
{
    "status": "ready",
    "message": "Environment is ready to use."
}
```

detail status of my cloud9 environment:

```
aws cloud9 describe-environments --environment-id 23104b5e40ee441ab9cefb8b7f7164dc
{
    "environments": [
        {
            "id": "23104b5e40ee441ab9cefb8b7f7164dc",
            "name": "eks-workshop",
            "description": "",
            "type": "ec2",
            "connectionType": "CONNECT_SSH",
            "arn": "arn:aws:cloud9:ap-southeast-1:259151278737:environment:23104b5e40ee441ab9cefb8b7f7164dc",
            "ownerArn": "arn:aws:iam::259151278737:user/it.terraform_user",
            "lifecycle": {
                "status": "CREATED"
            },
            "managedCredentialsStatus": "DISABLED_BY_DEFAULT"
        }
    ]
}
```

However when I login to the AWS console, under Cloud9 resources, it still shows as *No Access* under Permissions and I still can't open the IDE as its greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

Each Cloud9 environment has one and only one owner, who is the environment creator. You probably creating the environment with one user/role, and try to access it with another. Try to create the environment with the same user/role as the one who will eventually use it from the console.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).